# Can action overflow be anywhere other than the far right?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an application with multiple pages, all of which will be using the ActionBarSherlock on top and on the bottom. The top bar will not have any actions, all actions will be held in the bottom bar.

Every page on in my application uses 2 actions, but some also have other actions. Therefore, some pages will need the action overflow and some will not.

I want to keep the 2 actions that are always used all the way to the right to ensure that they are in the same place on every page, with the overflow button appearing in the middle sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to keep the 2 actions that are always used all the way to the right to ensure that they are in the same place on every page, with the overflow button appearing in the middle sometimes.

You can't do that, sorry. When present, the overflow button will always be the furthest to the right.

Comment: In Android 4.2, they added more RTL support, where the action bar itself gets reversed for RTL languages (if you so choose). So, it is a wee bit more accurate to say that "the overflow button will always be at the end", where "end" will be the right side for LTR languages and the left side for RTL languages. See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Answer (score 1):

Overflow button is always to the right. But since it's so small, I wouldn't worry about it affecting your UX, as long as you always use a consistent order for your permanent actions.